# Space determine for a C program

Tags: memory, gcc, cygwin, gcc3

Can I determine the space taken by a C program. Currently I am using GCC compiler on WIndows XP. Actually I want to check how much space consume by the C program.

It is very good if some function tell me the size consume by other function in C.

```
ex- fun() consume 1028 bytes to run.
```

Comment: Do you mean space in memory or space on the disk?

Comment: space consume by my program for both space in memory or space on the disk

Comment: It's difficult to tell how much memory your program is using because it may be using shared memory, and any library functions you use will use their own memory which can't be determined accurately until the program is run.

Comment: @dreamlax thanks for your suggestions but can I determine space at last the program run

Comment: @dreamlax or I can get the stack size consumed by program

Answer (score 0):

On disk: Sure: Compile it, make `ls` or `dir`.

In memory: No. Just imagine a program that load something from internet into memory. As the memory gets allocated dynamic and you dont know in advance how big the data is, it is impossible to tell the memory usage (in theory thats just a consequence from the halting problem).